# quickbooks-ruby not providing me with code

Tags: ruby, quickbooks

I'm trying to following this tutorial (https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby), but having a fairly tough time with just the authorization process alone.

When I get to:

```
grant_url = oauth2_client.auth_code.authorize_url(
redirect_uri: redirect_url, 
response_type: "code", 
state: SecureRandom.hex(12), 
scope: "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting")
```

I'm able to retrieve a URL as shown below:

```
[3] pry(#<QuickBooksAPI>)> grant_url
=> "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.intuit.com%2Fv2%2FOAuth2Playground%2FRedirectUrl&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&state=7f9bc5576701824b00948b0d"
```

However, I cannot POST to that URL as both the tutorials there ***and*** [QuickBook's tutorial shows](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#step-1-prepare-authorization-request) (Step 2)

For example:

```
curl -X POST "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.intuit.com%2Fv2%2FOAuth2Playground%2FRedirectUrl&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&state=7f9bc5576701824b00948b0d" -IL
HTTP/2 301
date: Mon, 15 Jun 2020 20:22:18 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 162
location: https://appcenter.intuit.com/app/connect/oauth2?client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.intuit.com%2Fv2%2FOAuth2Playground%2FRedirectUrl&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&state=7f9bc5576701824b00948b0d
server: nginx
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
strict-transport-security: max-age=3156000; includeSubDomains; preload

HTTP/2 302
date: Mon, 15 Jun 2020 20:22:18 GMT
content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
content-length: 462
location: https://accounts.intuit.com/index.html?partner_uid_button=google&offering_id=Intuit.sbg-fms.ippdevx&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fappcenter.intuit.com%2Fapp%2Fconnect%2Foauth2%3Fclient_id%3D[redacted]%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdeveloper.intuit.com%252Fv2%252FOAuth2Playground%252FRedirectUrl%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dcom.intuit.quickbooks.accounting%26state%3D7f9bc5576701824b00948b0d
server: nginx
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000
intuit_tid: 1-5ee7d87a-25f166b2947496d0c2c100a2
x-spanid: 962ae824-607c-4931-9371-8c3041631191
x-amzn-trace-id: Self=1-5ee7d87a-bf3269a880c6b7f81ac515d8;Root=1-5ee7d87a-25f166b2947496d0c2c100a2
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
x-download-options: noopen
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: private,no-cache,no-store,pre-check=0,post-check=0,must-revalidate
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
set-cookie: hosted-shell=%7B%22clientId%22%3A%22a5ba4c02-daa7-46b8-9dd9-42375f6eeea6%22%7D; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 13 Jun 2030 20:22:18 GMT; Secure
vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
strict-transport-security: max-age=3156000; includeSubDomains; preload

HTTP/2 411
server: AkamaiGHost
mime-version: 1.0
content-type: text/html
content-length: 223
expires: Mon, 15 Jun 2020 20:22:18 GMT
date: Mon, 15 Jun 2020 20:22:18 GMT
```

If I try POSTing using Ruby, I get the same error as Curl:

```
[15] pry(#<QuickBooksAPI>)> res = WebRequest.new.post_request(grant_url, "")
=> #<Net::HTTPMovedPermanently 301 Moved Permanently readbody=true>
```

My `WebRequest` post code:

```
    def post_request(url, data, headers="")
        uri = URI.parse(url)
        if !uri.query.nil?
            post_url = "#{uri.path}?#{uri.query}"
        else
            post_url = uri.path
        end
        https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        https.use_ssl = true
        https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("#{post_url}")
        request.body = data

        # Add headers if necessary.
        if !headers.empty?
            headers.each {|key, value| request[key] = value}
        end

        response = https.request(request)
        return response
    end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry. I clarified. I'm getting the exact URL in the output with the exception of my clientID being redacted

Comment: You should post how you are trying to POST to that URL so we can see that since that appears to be the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is that I cannot POST to the URL with the `quickbooks-ruby` gem because the README says that this happens in the user's browser. Therefore, I tried QuickBook's way. Quickbook's example shows the POST request using curl, which is how I tried (and showed) it in my case.

Comment: There are many libraries in ruby that can issue a POST request. Also Intuit has a client of their own [intuit-oauth](https://github.com/intuit/oauth-rubyclient) that might help.

Comment: Thanks. When I try just a standard POST request using a library from Ruby, it gives me the same error/response as curl, which is the 400 error. Updated post to reflect results.

Comment: It appears there is a workflow to the authorization whereby the user authorizes the application *"Once the user has authorized your app, an authorization code will be sent to your RedirectURL defined in your client."* [From the official Docs](https://github.com/intuit/oauth-rubyclient#exchange-authorization-code-for-oauth-20-token) it seems the url you were given is to be provided to a customer then they authorize and the codes are sent to the url you provide as the redirect

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick.